# A Crucial Riddle This Is

Tags: riddle

> A very vital thing I am
>
> That no one can survive without me
>
> I light your every path
>
> And help your eyes see the world
>
> Don't mistake me for my twin brother
>
> Though we sound the same
>
> We are totally different

Hint :

> This thing always moves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sun!

because

> it creates light and without the sun, nothing can live. The sun is not the same thing as a son! And it always moves.

Comment: Correct answer :)

Comment: Oh, so close I was

Comment: I know right. Did the hint give it away or was it something else? @1848

Comment: Did you know I've never got a question right in puzzling stack exchange?

Comment: Really? I thought you were one of the best users in this site @Duck

Comment: Nope! quantumtwinkie and riley are like the most well known

Comment: Also, put the @ before the comment

Comment: @Duck. Haha, Still I think you're really good :)

Comment: @Duck Don't worry! I think you write some great questions!

Comment: @Kevin L Yeah the hint helped!

Comment: @1848 I see. :)

Answer (score 1):

Is the answer

> light?

No one can survive without

> light

I light your every path

> yes, light lights stuff

Don't mistake me for my twin brother

> light, as in this feather is very light

We sound the same though

> yes, they do

We are totally different

> In meaning, yes

Comment: +1 Nice answer but unfortunately incorrect! That's a very close answer still :)

Comment: Is it bright? That would be close

Comment: Wrong answer mate. Just added a hint :)

Comment: Oh, ok, I'll think of something else

Comment: Is the answer eyes?

Comment: Or is it pupils

Comment: Nope. You're getting even further from the intended solution. The solution actually has something to do with your first answer