# New riddle, hot off the presses!

Tags: riddle

Surely I'm the most dangerous thing you could see.

But the truth is you could never live without me.

I keep it simple, inside I'm mostly just one character.

Half the time you don't even notice or care.

I help you look but you could never view me actually.

Mistake one letter and you might decide I'm not girly.

Hint:

> Just one hint twice for the true gumSHOEs: There can ONLY be one.

Edit: Ignore the hint if you're getting distracted by it.

Comment: Probably way too easy but this is my first riddle here - be kind! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Sun

Surely I'm the most dangerous thing you could see.

> Don't look at the sun

But the truth is you could never live without me.

> Source of most heat / light / energy

Half the time you don't even notice or care.

> Night time

Mistake one letter and you might decide I'm not girly.

> Sun -> Son

Comment: What about "I keep it simple, inside I'm mostly just one character." as well as the hint? :)

Comment: You got it! I guess I made it too easy.

Comment: I don't get the hint or the one character parts still though...

Comment: The hint highlights two words (shoe and just) which are related to the word "sole" (e.g. a shoe has a sole, and only = sole) which if you say it, sounds like "Sol" which is the name of the star of our solar system.

The one character refers to the chemical symbol for Hydrogen, "H." I thought using the word "letter" would make it too easy, so used the word "character."

Comment: Thought about that answer before you put it, but then I thought it was kind of from this:https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69958/a-crucial-riddle-this-is/69960#69960

Comment: Whoops, my comment above should read shoe and only, not just.

Comment: @Duck Wow! That's very similar. But no, I never saw that and don't think I've heard it before. Too common of a subject I guess.